# Controller 'uiTreeNodes', required by directive 'ngInclude', can't be found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, angular-ui-tree

I'm trying to use [angularui-tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree) and after days of struggle to make it run inside Vistulaforce(salesforce) page, it still shows some error or the other. Now I'm trying to run basic nested tree ui example but it's throwing an error and I can't see why when I'm doing all as per their instructions. Could anyone pl. help me understanding what's going wrong.

visualforce page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.4/angular.min.js"/>
        <link   rel = "stylesheet" href  = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-tree/2.22.1/angular-ui-tree.min.css"/>
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-tree/2.22.1/angular-ui-tree.min.js"/>
        <link   rel = "stylesheet" href  = "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>  

        <script                src   = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"/>
        <script                src   = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.js"/>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.tree']);
    app.controller('treeCtrl', function($scope) {



        $scope.tree1 = [];


        $scope.tree1 = [{
            'id': 1,
            'title': 'tree1 - item1',
            'nodes': []
        }, {
            'id': 2,
            'title': 'tree1 - item2',
            'nodes': []
        }, {
            'id': 3,
            'title': 'tree1 - item3',
            'nodes': []
        }, {
            'id': 4,
            'title': 'tree1 - item4',
            'nodes': []
        }];
        $scope.tree2 = [{
            'id': 1,
            'title': 'tree2 - item1',
            'nodes': []
        }, {
            'id': 2,
            'title': 'tree2 - item2',
            'nodes': []
        }, {
            'id': 3,
            'title': 'tree2 - item3',
            'nodes': []
        }, {
            'id': 4,
            'title': 'tree2 - item4',
            'nodes': []
        }];

        $scope.remove = function (scope) {
            scope.remove();
        };

        $scope.toggle = function (scope) {
            scope.toggle();
        };

        $scope.newSubItem = function (scope) {
            var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
            nodeData.nodes.push({
                id: nodeData.id * 10 + nodeData.nodes.length,
                title: nodeData.title + '.' + (nodeData.nodes.length + 1),
                nodes: []
            });
        };



});
```

```
       <div ng-app="MyApp">
            <div ng-controller="treeCtrl">

                <div ui-tree="ui-tree">
                  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="tree1" id="tree-root">
                    <li ng-repeat="node in tree1" ui-tree-node="ui-tree-node" ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
                  </ol>
                </div>

                <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
                  <div ui-tree-handle="ui-tree-handle">
                    {{node.title}}
                  </div>
                  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.nodes">
                    <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" ui-tree-node="ui-tree-node" ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
                    </li>
                  </ol>
                </script>


        </div>
     </div>
```

Error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for `angular-ui-tree`

https://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/gt00pr9x/

Note: jQuery is not required as angular-ui-tree is based on Pure Javascript

Comment: For me also ,I have a working fiddle but when I'm trying to copy the exact same thing to run with visualforce page, it's giving me that error. Also if I remove `ng-include` lines, then it won't show any error. But I need nesting so I need some way to use ng-include

Comment: The same as the header title of this question.